# How should I go about creating a multiplayer pac-man game in python?

Tags: python, pygame

For some context, I am making a Pac-Man game (using pygame) and I need a little guidance on how to structure the multiplayer side (using sockets). I have a few ideas (the first of which I have tried)

Have the clients send their move (north, east, south or west) to a server. Then, have the server move sprites with these moves and send back the images of each sprite so all the clients can then draw them on the screen. (I have tried this but keep getting an error as I think the data takes too long to send.

I could have the server simply relay all incoming moves to all other clients, but I feel as though this may lead to glitches if the connection is slow for one of the clients (i.e. the different client screens may go out of sync with nothing to correct them as all they are receiving are instructions. I think this would be relatively simple to implement.

Another option would be to send the positions of each sprite over the network instead of the move. This way if any client experienced lag their screen would be corrected as soon as they reconnect. This would, however, be the hardest to implement as I would have to write new sprite classes and I'm lazy.

My question is, do these make any sense at all? Why don't they make sense (because I doubt they do)? Is there a better way to approach this task entirely?

Thanks in advance, I'll try and stay active to quickly answer questions.

Comment: _"This would, however, be the hardest to implement as I would have to write new sprite classes and I'm lazy."_ comments like these result in downvotes.

Comment: _"do these make any sense at all"_ You're proposing the two main methods that games use to implement multiplayer. You should research for these and then try them...

Comment: Just trying to be friendly, it’s not that I’m lazy it’s that my time is valuable as I have many more features to implement the effect is the same. I have given it some research I just wanted a little direction. Don’t really care about your downvotes mate 

Comment: Others' time is valuable too. If you're not willing to invest time to write a class (it doesn't have to be a sprite class; the sprite rendering is a client responsibility that has nothing whatsoever to do with networking. Your "NetworkCharacter" class could implement the network replicated movement logic, then just provide coordinates where your client's render loop draws the standard sprite object you already have), then why should others invest their time to help you? Demonstrate that you're working hard to solve this problem and you'll find folks will be inspired to work hard to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I was thinking about making a MMO, and also had lots of questions about how to handle data on the network.

Gladly, I found [this](http://repositorio.roca.utfpr.edu.br/jspui/bitstream/1/5985/1/PG_COADS_2011_2_06.pdf) amazing article (too bad it's in portuguese) by [Ivan Luiz Picoli](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=xwAKcE4AAAAJ&hl=en) called *"Server-Client Architecture in multiplayer games"* (he also uses PyGame), in which he analyzes 2 main methods of doing so:

- **Sending player's coordinates** (topic 3.5.2.1 of the article)
  This technique consists on the client sending it's X and Y coordinates everytime it moves. The implementation is pretty easy, but the results are not that good. This may lead to miss syncing and server overload. If you try to fix the overload by sending all coordinates at a certain time on a loop, this might result in "jumpy" sprites, as if there were frames being skipped on the players movement. We can assume this is not a good approach.
- **Sending player's actions** (topic 3.5.2.2 of the article)
  All the player sends is its actions, such as "move_forward", then the server broadcasts this to other clients and they can "emulate" what another remote client is doing. This fixes many issues that happen when we only send coordinates, such as overload and the "frame skipping" effect, but this implementation must be done very carefully and send only important and relevant actions.

By reading this I personally think it's a very good idea to **mix both methods**. You mainly use the second method, but from time to time you send coordinates, in order to fix some small discrepancies.